# JavaFX WebView: how to block resources from a specific website?

Tags: java, html, javafx, webview

Is there a way to block resources (images, scripts, css sheets, etc) from either a specific website or all websites when using the JavaFX WebView?

Basically, I would like to stop the `src` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_src.asp) and `href` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp) from working depending on their content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to add a content security policy via a meta tag at the very beginning of the document:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=style-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```